# maximum Canberra distance

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

The Canberra distance is a sum-weighted version of the Manhattan distance as follows:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{|p_i-q_i|}{|p_i|+|q_i|}$$

where $p$ and $q$ are two ranked lists or vectors.

Is there a way to compute the maximum possible distance of an ordered vector? e.g. if we have $(1,2,3,4,5)$ compared only with permutations of itself, what can be the maximum distance? My guess is that $(5,4,3,2,1)$ will be one of the permutations that will produce the maximum. However, is there any analytical way to do this?

The reason I as is I would like to normalize the distance between 0 and 1.

Comment: [The extremum is $(3,\,4,\,5,\,1,\,2)$](https://repl.it/repls/PettyLikableConnection).

Comment: @J.G. That's some nifty coding!

Comment: @J.G. thanks for the efficient code, though it would help me and others who see this question if you post it with comments. Still, looking for an analytical method if possible. For example if this code is run with manhattan distance, both $(5,4,3,2,1$ and $(3,4,5,1,2)$ give the same maximum

Comment: also, the brute force method is very costly for medium size arrays, for example, n=16

Comment: @ha554an Well-spotted that the optimum isn't unique; I should probably have written code that finds everything tied. The code *is* only quick for small $n$, but they're enough for us to form a conjecture.

Comment: Update: are you *sure* $(5,\,4,\,3,\,2,\,1)$ is a maximum? For me, it only scores $2.0$, whereas the maximum is $2.1$. (To see this, I've amended line 15.)

Comment: No, you're right that $(5,4,3,2,1)$ is not a maximum for Canberra. I just tried the same code with manhattan distance where I know that should be the maximum, but so is $(3,4,5,1,2)$. I'm not certain if there are only multiple solutions to manhattan, and maybe not canberra. Sorry for the confusion!